# Can I use Fix-a-Flat after it froze solid?

Tags: tires, troubleshooting

I have a can of fix-a-flat in my car, and when the temperature dropped last week, the stuff froze solid. I didn't notice any damage to the can.

Is it compromised? If that's a possibility, then I will just replace it. Don't want to find out the hard way.

Comment: As a side note most TPS (tire pressure sensors) manufacturers advise  not using quick fix tire products. The sealant plugs the sensor port. Fix-a flat however says it can be cleaned and reused.

Comment: Most of my vehicles are old and don't have tire pressure sensors in them. Good to know, though, @mikes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Fix-A-Flat](http://www.fixaflat.com/faq/) website FAQ, it's still good once thawed:

> Yes, if the temperature falls below 32 degrees Fahrenheit it will freeze. The product in the can is not damaged and may be used after thawing. If the product is in the tire, and freezing weather is predicted, then immediately take the vehicle to a qualified tire professional for repair.